# Gmail & Dragon Dictate for Mac

Tags: voice-recognition

I'm trying to create commands for a specific website context (Gmail). However, the commands aren't being recognized. I have tried the following URLs for the website context:

```
 https://mail.google.com/
 https://mail.google.com/*
 *mail.google.com*
```

I watched [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6S20Ga30DM) for instruction, and I don't see where I'm going wrong.

I'm testing it with just a simple command: saying "New tab" should issue the key-combo <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. However, with the cursor in a text box in Gmail, the words "New tab" simply get written out like standard Dictation mode; they aren't recognized as a command.